# Linux Problem solving: Need a solution to monitor active log file via BMC tool

Tags: linux, monitoring

I need some help on this one.

The application writes logs along with timestamp in the file name.
example: log_20072020 Plus if size of file reaches 500MB it creates a new log_20072020_1 (with an underscore)

Every day new active log file with a date in the log name.

The problem is: The BMC log monitoring can only monitor a STATIC Logfile and my log files keep changing with tailing date, each day about 5 - 6 files as log size grows.

I need a solution to duplicate the ACTIVE log file to a Static name log file, and when new log file initiates then that active log must now start writing to the static-name file.

Simply put: at any point the current active log must be writing to the common log file name.

Hope someone can help me here.

Regards,
MU

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

For the active log: Dont move it and dont delete it. After copy/cat and gzip it to an archive file just put the length to zero with:

```
echo -n >/var/log/whatever/activelogfile
```

...and assoziated programms ( see lsof ) dont lose connection to that logfile.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate, i want a script to actively handle maintaining a single active log whos name will not change? Currently, my active log names keep changing and I can't point my monitoring tool to the latest log as it only accepts the static name.

Comment: I think logrotate - https://linuxconfig.org/logrotate is exactly the tool you need because it rotates ( before 500MB reached ) and do something like above "echo".

Comment: ...and if a cronjob do above "echo" after rotating it by simple commands before the 500MB reached the application that rotates at 500MB have no chance to do this.